# Compute the limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Consider $s_n = (100n)^{\frac{100}{n}}$. Describe $s_1$(1 followed by how many zeros?). Repeat for $s_{10}$. Now compute the limit $lim s_n$.

I computed $s_1$ followed by 100 zeros, and $s_{10}$ followed by 30 zeros. And I thought the limit of $s_n$ may converge to 1. But I don't know how to prove it.

Any suggestion? Appreciate!

Comment: Are you sure you have 100 zeros? The instructions say 1 followed by x number of zeros.

Comment: @AlexRuiz I'm not sure. I have no idea about it.

Comment: So if you find $s_1=(100\cdot 1)^{100/1}=100^{100}=(10^2)^{100}=10^{200}$ so you would actually have 1 followed by 200 zeros. Try now for $s_{10}$.

Comment: For the limit, consider writing $s_n=e^{\frac{100}n\log(100n)}$ and using L’Hopital’s rule for $\frac{100}n\log(100n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this with calculus, but if you want nitty gritty analysis:

So, $(100n)^{\frac{100}{n}} = 100^{\frac{100}{n}}n^{\frac{100}{n}}$.

As $100^x$ is a continuous function, and the limit of $\frac{100}{n}$ is $0$, we have the following:  for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$, such that $-\delta < x < \delta$ implies $|100^x - 1| < \epsilon$. Furthermore, there exists some $N$, such that for all $n > N$, $0 < \frac{100}{n} < \delta$. Combining these two observations, we conclude the limit of $100^{\frac{100}{n}}$ is $1$.

Now, for the more difficult one: Luckily, we only have to prove $\sqrt[n]{n}$ goes to 1. After all, multiplication is a continuous operation, and thus it preserves limits, so if the limit of $\sqrt[n]{n}$ is one, so is the limit of $\sqrt[n]{n}^{100}$. To show $\sqrt[n]{n}$ goes to $1$, let $\epsilon > 0$ be some number. It is easy to show that $(1 + \epsilon)^n$ goes to infinity, so let $N$ be a number, such that for all $n > \frac{N}{3}$, $(1 + \epsilon)^n > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$. Now, assume $n > N$. Also assume $N$ is divisible by $3$ just to make life easier. Then $(1 + \epsilon)^n = (1 + \epsilon)^{\frac{N}{3}}(1 + \epsilon)^{n - \frac{N}{3}}$.  This is larger than or equal to $\frac{2}{\epsilon}(1 + \epsilon)^{n - \frac{N}{3}}$. If you wanted to get super formal, you would need to use induction for this next part, but I will just argue that, since $\frac{2}{\epsilon}(1 + \epsilon) = \frac{2}{\epsilon} + 2$, every time we multiply by $(1 + \epsilon)$, we add at least $2$ to our number. As $n - \frac{N}{3} > \frac{n}{2}$, this ensures $(1 + \epsilon)^n > n$, and thus $1 < \sqrt[n]{n} < 1 + \epsilon.$ This means $\sqrt[n]{n}$ goes to $1$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot!